# Classification and Grouping of Sorted Data

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, grouping, unique

I have a Dataset H3:J12 where components are classified based on Type. I have summed the count for similar components and sorted based on Count with Unique and Sort formulae and the result is L3:M7.
In my actual case, there are several thousands of such components which are sorted as in L:L and now I would like to add the Type column next to the Component with sorted Count as shown in P3:R12. Is it possible to extract them directly from L3:M7 or directly from H3:J12, as I will not be able to do them manually.

[image: Dataset]

Comment: Related questions: [How can I "group by" and sum a column in excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/405555/how-can-i-group-by-and-sum-a-column-in-excel); [Count with grouping in excel](https://superuser.com/questions/1297192/count-with-grouping-in-excel)

Comment: Thank you @Stef! I did accomplish the desire output with Pivot table

Answer (score 0):

Screenshots/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j99DlbDzw0n6LQiIZ5?e=Ye57d8) refer:

Mechanical approaches include pivots, VB, etc.  However, you could consider a more dynamic approach that doesn't require constant updating / refreshing (of code, pivots, etc.) whenever underlying data is appended/amended.

**YES**: you can retrieve *directly* from source data as follows:

[image: Sort unique formula]

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(C3:D20))
```

---

[image: Sumifs]

```
=SUMIFS(E3:E30,C3:C30,H3:H17,D3:D30,I3:I17)
```

---

*Notes*:

1. Could make this averageif(s), countif(s), percentile etc. etc. - another
   significant advantage over alternative methods (VB, pivots, etc.), besides dynamic nature, is the flexibility re: measures; restrictions present in pivots are substantive in relation to Excel direct calculation
2. Disadvantage is inability to automatically chart data using pivot chart functionality that accompanies pivot tables
3. See linked sheet opening line for conditional formatting sample used to recreate 'look / feel' you might otherwise be losing out on with this approach
4. It seemed as though you were almost there!  I'm not sure what relevance other tables have (ignored this in light of question).

Comment: thank you for sharing a dynamic approach to sorting the unique data. I would definitely use your approach, but I do see the sum of count has to be sorted once again by this approach. From your data, B whose sum is 69 has to be listed top and then C, D and A. When I sort the output data this time, the component and types will not be in the same order.

Comment: you can put the output in cols H and I in any order (so long as A corresponds A1, A2, ... etc. and likewise for B -> B1, B2,... etc. , and C, etc....

Comment: I simply sorted cols H and I (using a formula mind you, which should be handled automatically) for presentational convenience - this assumes I follow you... :) let me know what you mean by "B, followed by C, D and *A* ?)